# Why Apache IoTDB reported `WrappedthreadPoolExecutor` error on timestamp insertion?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What is the reason for this error? `ERROR o.a,i.c.c,t. WrappedthreadPoolExecutor: 111 - Exception in thread pool org.apache. iotdb.threadpool:type=Compaction-Sub-Task`, and then it reported that I got my inserted timestamp wrong, but I checked that it should right (new data later than the written time series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by out-of-order data between data files of Apache IoTDB. This can be fixed by upgrading to the latest version (1.3) of Apache IoTDB.